# How to add "TikZ" symbol in a document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

How do I add the TikZ symbol to a document? Examples of others are \TeX and \LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

TikZ does not provide a macro to produce its name, but the documentation uses:

```
\def\tikzname{Ti\emph{k}Z}
```

**update** although looking at this definition, it might produce unexpected results in an italicized passage.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!